# Apexcharts localization in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apexcharts

We are using apexcharts-react in our react app and usually we use typescript. We would now like to set the localization of the apex charts based on a custom cookie.

According to [the documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/localization/) this works like the following:

```
Apex.chart = {
  locales: [...localeConfigurationObject],
  defaultLocale: "en"
}
```

I would like to do this setting in a typescript file though but can not find the type definitions of `Apex` anywhere. Any tips welcome.

Comment: this could help [ApexChart types](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/blob/32eb6af44be83c5b0698a9fa5c80b50437578fe3/types/apexcharts.d.ts)

Comment: I already found those types but I don't know how they could help me - there is no `Apex` type and I don't know how to get a reference to this global thing from Apexcharts and of what type it is.